# Passing Form to Template using RenderWith method

Tags: silverstripe

I am using the Silverstripe comments module by Willr along with an implementation of DataObjects as Pages.

The comments module allows you to attach comments to Data Objects - which I have done. The problem I am having is that when I attempt to pass through customfields from the Datobject to a template using renderwith, the CommentsForm that gets passed renders the form, but does not associate any comments made through the passed form with the DataObject.

Here is my action and renderWith method on my PostsPageHolder:

```
    public function view($request) {
    $segment = $request->param('ID');

    if ($obj = Post::get()->filter('URLSegment', $segment)->First()) :
        switch ($obj->Type) {
            case 'News-Post' :
                return $this->renderWith(
                    array('PostsPage_view_news', 'Page'),
                    array(
                        'Object'        => $obj,
                        'Type'          => $obj->Type,
                        'Title'         => $obj->Title,
                        'Entry'         => $obj->Entry,
                        'CommentsForm'  => $obj->CommentsForm
                    )
                );
                break;
    ...
}
```

Does anyone know how I can pass through the form using the RenderWith() array?

Comment: figured this out - you need to pass 'CommentsForm' => $obj->CommentsForm()

Answer (score 2):

try `customise(array)` as shown here https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/tutorials/site_search/#showing-the-results

```
return $this->customise(array(
    'Object'        => $obj,
    'Type'          => $obj->Type,
    'Title'         => $obj->Title,
    'Entry'         => $obj->Entry,
    'CommentsForm'  => $obj->CommentsForm
))->renderWith(
    array('PostsPage_view_news', 'Page')
);
```